# Find a LTI system such that $\mathcal{T}\{\frac{\sin t}{t}\} = \frac{\sin 2t}{t}$

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, linear-systems, frequency-response, impulse-response

> Let 
>   $$x(t) = \frac{\sin t}{t} \qquad\text{and}\qquad y(t) = \frac{\sin 2t}{t}$$
>
> - Is it possible to find a LTI system such that $\mathcal{T}\{x(t)\} = y(t)$?
> - If not, what's the reason for that?

**My try:**

Assuming frequency response exists

$$Y(j\omega) = H(j\omega)X(j\omega) \tag{*}$$

Since $$\mathcal F\left\{\frac{\sin Wt}{\pi t}\right\} =\begin{cases} 1 &|\omega|\lt W \\0 &|\omega|\gt W\end{cases}$$
We have $$X(j\omega) =\begin{cases} \pi &|\omega|\lt 1 \\0 &|\omega|\gt 1\end{cases}$$
And $$Y(j\omega) =\begin{cases} \pi &|\omega|\lt 2 \\0 &|\omega|\gt 2\end{cases}$$
So it's not possible to find $H(j\omega)$ such that $(^*)$ holds. Because if $|\omega| \gt 1$ we have $X(j\omega) = 0$ which implies $Y(j\omega) = 0$ contradicting $Y(j\omega) = \pi$ for $1\lt |\omega| \lt 2$.

- Is my argument right?
- Also how we can prove the impossibility for the case frequency response doesn't exist? What's the intuition for this? I mean is it intuitively clear that we can't have $\mathcal{T}\{x(t)\} = y(t)$ for LTI system?

Comment: You are correct. For an argument as to why in the _opposite direction_ (that is, $\mathcal T\{x(t)]=x\left(\frac t2\right)$ instead of $\mathcal T\{x(t)]=2x(2t)$ as in your question), a linear but _not_ time-invariant system will work, see [this recent question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/68005/235) and its answers

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for your reply. How we can prove that when frequency response doesn't exist?

Comment: Do you have an example of an LTI system for which the frequency response does not exist in mind?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes, take a look: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/67302/determining-output-of-a-lti-system I think we can construct other non-stable systems as well such that frequency response doesn't exist.

Comment: No such LTI system can do this for you.  You have a divide-by-zero problem.  for $ 1 < \omega < 2$, your LTI system has to create non-zero energy at frequencies of where zero energy is input.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That's right. I wonder what would happen if frequency response doesn't exist. How we can prove that $\mathcal{T}\{\frac{\sin t}{t}\} = \frac{\sin 2t}{t}$ is impossible for any LTI system using only basic properties without resorting to Fourier transform to avoid the possibility that frequency response diverges?

Comment: you prove it by contradiction.  division-by-zero leads to contradiction.  i.e. dividing a non-zero number by zero leads to contradiction.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That works in the case frequency response supposed to exist. I mean proving using only linearity and time-invariability.

Comment: do you know how to prove, given ***only*** L and TI, how to prove that the output $y(t)$ is the convolution of the input $x(t)$ and some "$h(t)$" that we can interpret as an impulse response?  can you do that?  then try this for an input: $$ x(t) = A \cos(\omega t + \theta) $$ and see what comes out.